# Counting of elements in list not producing expected result

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, python-2.7

I have a pandas dataframe dftouse['col a'] which consists of lists :

```
0        []                            
1        [carbon, nature]              
2        [Lincoln]                     
3        [CBDC]                        
4        []
```

I want to count elements in each list across the rows. When I am executing

```
dftouse['Col a'].apply(lambda x: (len(x)-1) if not x else len(x))

0        1
1        2
2        1
3        1
4        1
```

Expected :

```
0        0
1        2
2        1
3        1
4        0
```

It would be helpful if I can get help debugging this. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `str.len()` on the column

```
>>> dftouse['col a'].str.len()
0    0
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    0
Name: col a, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `len` on `apply`:

```
>>> dftouse['Col a'].apply(len)

0    0
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    0
Name: Col a, dtype: int64
```